# Замена всех вхождений в группе regexp

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка вида:

```
"{
    "text": {
        "message":"123123123123 "123123123123" "123123" 123123123123",
    }
}"
```

С помощью preg_replace пытаюсь заменить все " на \", которые находятся внутри строки "123123123123 "123123123123" "123123" 123123123123", но находит только первую кавычку в группе.
Регулярное выражение:

```
/\"message\":\".+?(\").+?\",/
```

В итоге хочу получить это:

```
"{
    "text": {
        "message":"123123123123 \"123123123123\" \"123123\" 123123123123",
    }
}"
```

Есть у кого какие идеи как это сделать?

Comment: и что вы будете делать, когда текст будет `qwe "asd ", zxc` ?

Comment: если у вас json сформированный через одно место, то решите проблему с его формированием, а не бейтесь с результатами плодя костыли

Comment: Такой json прилетает, ничего поделать не могу с этим. Поэтому только так

Comment: Что-то вроде `preg_replace ('/ "(\d+)"/', ' \"$1\"', $bad_json_text)`

Comment: `preg_replace_callback` можете использовать

Comment: Да, что-то вроде `preg_replace_callback('~("[^"]*"\s*:\s*")(.*)"(?=[]},]|$)~m', function($m) { return $m[1] . str_replace('"', '\\"', $m[2]) . '"'; }, $text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew думается там жестко привязано к формату `message:"(.*)",\s*}`